# ngrx effect throws "dispatched an invalid action: undefined"

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have this effect for logout confirmation under the condition of a dialog response, but am getting the following errors:

> ERROR Error: Effect "AuthEffects.logoutConfirmation$" dispatched an invalid action: undefined

and

> ERROR TypeError: Actions must be objects

heres the effect:

```
@Effect()
logoutConfirmation$ = this.actions$
    .ofType<Logout>(AuthActionTypes.Logout)
    .pipe(
      map(action => {
        if (action.confirmationDialog) {
          this.dialogService
            .open(LogoutPromptComponent)
            .afterClosed()
            .pipe(
              map(confirmed => {
                if (confirmed) {
                  return new LogoutConfirmed();
                } else {
                  return new LogoutCancelled();
                }
              })
            );
        } else {
          return new LogoutConfirmed();
        }
      })
    );
```

it works when confirmation dialog is activated, I guess it's something wrong with the map of the dialog's response, have been trying to understand it but couldn't fin a way.
Any one has a clue on this?

Comment: Is it a runtime or compiletime error ?

Comment: no, it's when the action is dispatched.

Comment: Try adding `return this.dialogService //etc...`

Comment: got

Effect "AuthEffects.logoutConfirmation$" dispatched an invalid action: [object Object]

and

Actions must have a type property

Comment: Declare the explicit type of `logoutConfirmation$` as `logoutConfirmation$:Observable<Action>` and see what happens ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your outer map should be a `mergeMap`, as you are mapping the action to a new stream (in case that the condition is true).

You can fix this as follows:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import {map, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Effect()
logoutConfirmation$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType<Logout>(AuthActionTypes.Logout)
    .pipe(
      mergeMap(action => {
        if (action.confirmationDialog) {
          return this.dialogService
            .open(LogoutPromptComponent)
            .afterClosed()
            .pipe(
              map(confirmed => confirmed ? new LogoutConfirmed():new LogoutCancelled())
            );
        } else {
          return of(new LogoutConfirmed());
        }
      })
    );
```

As a side note, always declare the explicit type of your effects in order to get errors at compile instead of run time.

Comment: What do you mean by declaring the explicit type of effects to get errors at compile time?

Answer (score 8):

In my case I wasn't dispatching anything so putting `dispatch:false` inside of `@effect()` fixed my issue.

> @Effect({dispatch: false})

Answer (score 0):

this happens when you don't call this action type in your reducer you need to put something like this in your reducer with same action type you are using in your effect :

```
case AuthActionTypes.Logout:
            return {
                ...state
            };
```

@Stephen Romero answer will work but it will ignore dispatching new values